# Apache suEXEC execute script on user dir basis?

Tags: apache-2.2, suexec

Iam looking for a way to run a script with different users.
I dont want to hardcode the users in the config... and I found some information that it should be possible that the user goes to... lets say:

Code:

```
http://localhost/~user1/myscript.cgi
```

and the script gets executes as user 'user1'.

Does anybody know if that is possible?
If not, do I have to make a new vhost config for every user?

Thanks a lot!
Greets,
Kodak

Answer (score 1):

Apache Doc (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html#usage) states that:

> Requests for CGI programs will call the suEXEC wrapper only if they
>   are for a virtual host containing a SuexecUserGroup directive or if
>   they are processed by mod_userdir.

Since your URL is of the kind "~user", which is provided by mod_userdir, I guess suExec is already running.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Yes, suExec is running and working with the SuexecUserGroup for the specified user. So when I get this right... this means that when I have mod_userdir configured it will work as I want?

Comment: You already have mod_userdir configured, otherwise the `/~user/` URL wouldn't work

Comment: It doesn´t work yet... I was just saying I would like to configure it as /~user/. Ok, I will just try it and report back...

Comment: Once you will have mod_userdir running, suExec will run too.